# Проксирование nginx websocket

Tags: nginx

Как правильно сделать проксирование трафика на вебсокете в конфиге nginx?
http://nginx.org/ru/docs/http/websocket.html

Допустим если сайт у нас расположен на 80 порте, а вебсокет по адресу ws://site.ru:2000

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Вопрос решался просто:

в http{} дописываем

```
map $http_upgrade $connection_upgrade {
    default upgrade;
    ''      close;
}

upstream websocket {
  server ваш_ип:2000;
}
```

в server{} дописываем

```
location /websocket {
    proxy_pass http://websocket;
    proxy_http_version 1.1;
    proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
    proxy_set_header Connection "Upgrade";
    proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
}
```

в nginx.conf дописываем

```
keepalive_timeout 604800;
proxy_connect_timeout 604800;
proxy_send_timeout 604800;
proxy_read_timeout 604800;
```

вебсокет открываем таким образом

```
var socket = new WebSocket("ws://ваш_ип_или_домен/websocket");
```

Comment: `proxy_set_header Connection "Upgrade";` нужно заменить на `proxy_set_header Connection $connection_upgrade;`, иначе объявление `map` выше не имеет смысла. Весь смысл этого `map` как раз в том, чтобы один и тот же upstream использовать как для websocket-соединений, так и для обычных http-соединений. Принцип работы в итоге такой: если в исходном запросе присутствует непустой заголовок `Upgrade`, то передать в upstream заголовок `Connection` со значением `upgrade`, иначе передать в upstream заголовок `Connection` со значением `close`.

Answer (score 0):

Не работает такой конфиг.
Выдается ошибка в консоли браузера:

> WebSocket connection to ws://site.com/ws failed: Error during
>   WebSocket handshake: Unexpected response code: 200

По этой ошибке очень-очень много вопросов по всем форумам, но ни одного ответа.
Такое ощущение, что не умеет реально nginx ws проксировать.
Проблема лечится легко, просто надо в js коде соединение с ws устанавливать с явным указанием порта

```
var socket = new WebSocket("ws://ваш_ип_или_домен:9999");
```

В этом случае сразу все работает.

Отсюда вопрос: зачем вообще проксировать ws через nginx?

Проверить Origin (хост с которого подключаются к ws) легко может сам ws сервер.
На ум приходит только одно: проксировать надо, чтобы избежать а-ля ddos атак на порт ws, чтобы обращения сначала фильтровал nginx а потом уже ws сервер.
Потому что теоретически ws сервер завалится гораздо быстрее nginx.

Есть ли в этом смысл - защищать таким образом ws сервер? Кто может обосновать?

Comment: Это поле для ответов! Задайте новый вопрос, если существующих ответов вам мало.

Comment: *просто надо в js коде соединение с ws устанавливать с явным указанием порта* ...если порт не 80, или, для `wss`, не 443. См. [RFC6455](https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc6455#page-14). Как обычно, в документации всё есть, просто глубже, чем ожидается.

Comment: Нам же надо надо, чтобы nginx пробросил нас на порт, на котором слушает ws сервер, то есть на 9999. Вместо этого nginx говорит: милый, у меня все хорошо, вот тебе ответ http 200, какие еще сокеты?))

Comment: Это уже получается в обход nginx, из-за чего теряется вся суть затеи, для чего бы она ни была нужна ТСу. Если хотите спросить о целесообразности этого, задайте отдельный вопрос.