# Как правильно настроить проксирование Nginx для websoket?

Tags: php, nginx, websocket, ispmanager

Нужно сделать WebSocket через SSL т.е. WSS.

На сайте без сертификата запустить сервер удалось, тестовый чат работает (библиотека Ratchet), но делаю тоже самое на сайте где стоит сертификат, естественно соединение не устанавливает.

Как я понял нужно сделать прокси через Nginx (установлен), через который будет проходить соединение.

У меня сервер VDS с установленной ISP Manager

Как правильно записать конфиги?

[Здесь](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/494996/%D0%9F%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%BA%D1%81%D0%B8%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5-nginx-websocket) ответ вроде бы похоже на то, что нужно, но где достать http{} чтобы вставить у меня его нет...

Опять же непонятно, внятных/понятных ответов нет вообще...

Прошу помогите очень нужно...

Comment: Почитайте на nginx.ru, там про это есть; также http{} это для nginx.conf файла

Comment: @DanielProtopopov про http{} там такого нет, мне его добавить нужно что ли?

Comment: Всё там есть, учитесь читать документацию - http://nginx.org/ru/docs/beginners_guide.html#conf_structure

Comment: @DanielProtopopov в основном файле есть, в файлах конфигураций для каждого отдельного домена нет.

Comment: @DanielProtopopov я перестраховываюсь, так как первый раз с этим сталкиваюсь, сломать не хотелось бы

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Долго мучался и много вопросов здесь задал, но так и не подсказали как сделать в итоге решил сам, ответ [здесь](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/757351/%D0%9F%D0%BE%D0%BC%D0%BE%D0%B3%D0%B8%D1%82%D0%B5-%D1%81-%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%BA%D1%81%D0%B8-nginx-%D0%B4%D0%BB%D1%8F-websocket/757402#757402)

Answer (score 0):

Конструкция

```
map $http_upgrade $connection_upgrade {
    default upgrade;
    ''      close;
}
```

прописывается в файл /etc/nginx/nginx.conf в секцию http { }

[Читаем первоисточник для просветления.](https://nginx.ru/ru/docs/http/websocket.html)

Comment: читал я его... толком не понял

Comment: это я добавил в /etc/nginx/nginx.conf, а вот где другую часть этого прокси настраивать, как понимаю location /ws/ { ... } вставить в server {} уже в настройках nginx самого сайта в блок который работает через сертификаты. Но вот как настроить именно на порт 4444 так как на нем работает websocket